# sqlite3_step() doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have this C++ function which works to check if a given name exists. But every time it returns false even when a given name already exists. Where do I do wrong?

```
bool Database::hasRepository(std::string repoName)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM repository WHERE NAME='";
    sql += repoName + "'";

    sqlite3_stmt* selectStmt = nullptr;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(connection, sql.c_str(), sql.size(), &selectStmt, NULL);
    int results = sqlite3_step(selectStmt);

    sqlite3_finalize(selectStmt);

    if(results == SQLITE_ROW)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: First off all you should use parameter markers instead of putting the filter value directly in the sql query. Secondly, what do you mean by 'it returns force'? Do you mean false?

Comment: I meant it return false while expecting true in a case where a name is already in the list. Any idea why use parameter markers is a good practice?

Answer (score 4):

You should check the return value of all functions which might return an error indication. For example, `sqlite3_prepare_v2` will return an error code if the statement has a syntax error.

That might have told you that the statement you supplied is incorrect (if it is).

You can use `sqlite3_errmsg` and `sqlite3_errstr` to produce more readable error messages. It is never a good idea to just throw away the specific information about the error, for example by just returning false, particularly during debugging.

Comment: AFAIR semicolons are not needed unless one is executing two statements in the same string, and in my case adding semicolon did not change anything.

Comment: @Amani: All the same, you should always check for errors. (A  `repoName` which needs escaping -- perhaps because it is a little-bobby-tables attack -- might also cause a syntax error, which is also why you should use parameter markers instead of naive string concatenation.)

Comment: I think your advice and Janick Bernet's on parameter markers is very valid and I will work on that. It turned out that the table name "repository" that I manually put into the sql string was not correct. Checking for its existence returned false. This was because the name was actually "repositories" and not "repository"

Comment: @Amani: I'll bet that would have been easier to diagnose if you'd done a better job of reporting errors. Just sayin'.

Comment: I totally agree. I was looking for a very simple singleton class for logging (two files framework, sort of), so that I could turn it off/on as needed during compilation. Any ideas on what is available out there?

Comment: @Amani: I use https://code.google.com/p/google-glog/ but it's far from "a very simple singleton class". However, it gets the job done and you don't need to think about it much. YMMV, obviously.